# Why doesn't subscribe work in a new browser window

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have a list of camera entries on an angular website. Clicking on an entry opens a new window and shows the camera as a livestream. But the subscribe is somehow not recognized.

**Important note:** Once the window is open, the following clicks on the list should not open new windows but add the livestreams to the previously opened window.

On a click, I open first the window and then call my service method. But the subscribe on the OnInit() method is not hit.

**OnClick:**

```
this.externalWindow = window.open(
          '/livesplit',
          '',
          'width=' + window.innerWidth + ',height=' + window.innerHeight
        );
//call service to add a cameraconfig
this.settingsService.changeCurrentCameraLivesplit(result);
```

**OnInit in the opened component:**

```
this.settingsService.currentCameraLivesplit.subscribe(currentCameraLivesplit => {
//this is never hit..
      if (currentCameraLivesplit) {
       this.currentcameraList.push(currentCameraLivesplit );
      }
    });
```

**My Service:**

```
  private cameraLivesplitSource = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  currentCameraLivesplit = this.cameraLivesplitSource.asObservable();

  changeCurrentCameraLivesplit(currentCameraLivesplit: CameraConfig[]) {
    this.cameraLivesplitSource.next(currentCameraLivesplit);
  }
```

does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Additional info:
The service is added in the app.module.ts under providers

I tried to create a Stackblitz(string should be added in this example under add button in 2nd window [only click add button in the first window!])

Stackblitz editor: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k9h1mn

Stackblitz app: https://angular-k9h1mn.stackblitz.io

Comment: I think what you did is correct, can you just check if when you invoke ** changeCurrentCameraLivesplit** (console.log inside the function)

Comment: i tried a console log in the service method "changeCurrentCameraLivesplit" and there have the right object in it. and hit also the breakpoint if I'll add one. but nothing happens in the subscribe

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz project with fake data.

Comment: I don't see an issue either ... waiting for the stackblitz

Comment: can it be that the observable is broken when a new window is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of trying around without success I assume that observable/subscribe does not work with an external window. However, I would like to share my solution here so that others who have the same problem can save a lot of working time:

First I create the new window:

```
let externalWindow = window.open(
   '/livesplit',
   '',
   'width=' + window.innerWidth + ',height=' + window.innerHeight
);
```

Call event:

```
externalWindow.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('eventname', {detail: 'data to send'}));
```

in component of the window:

```
@HostListener('window:eventname', ['$event'])
    testListener(event) {
      console.log(event.deatil);
    }
```